# Get all values of repeater subfields stored in DB

Tags: wordpress, while-loop, advanced-custom-fields, repeater

Currently, I'm struggling with ACF (advanced custom fields) repeater field. The first issue is the general architecture of this field type - it's not stored in the database in a single place, yet its multiplied (e.g. if my repeater field name is called workshops_grouping and subfield is called data, then there will be workshops_grouping_1_data, workshops_grouping_2_data etc.).

So I wanted to be smarter than ACF ( :) ) and I've thought that if I will use below code to get all post ids from CPT, then it will be easier. Here is the code:

```
<?php
    $other_page = get_posts( array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'fields' => 'ids',
        'post_type' => 'workshops',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
    ) );

if( have_rows('workshops_grouping', $other_page) ): ?>

    <select id="no1">

    <?php while( have_rows('workshops_grouping', $other_page) ): the_row(); ?>

        <option value="<?php the_sub_field('data'); ?>"><?php the_sub_field('data'); ?></option>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    </select>

    <select id="no2">

    <?php while( have_rows('workshops_grouping', $other_page) ): the_row(); ?>

        <option value="<?php the_sub_field('company'); ?>"><?php the_sub_field('company'); ?></option>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    </select>

<?php endif; ?>
```

But hey, guess what - it doesn't work at all. Meaning = it shows nothing. I've gone through a couple of similar posts here as well on the official community board of ACF. So far without success. Is it even doable?

Answer (score 0):

According to the ACF documentation, you have to pass an ID inside the have_rows function.
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/have_rows/

Now your passing the $other_page variable inside the function. This variable is an array with your pages. You need to loop this first and pass the post ID in de have_rows function.

your code will look like something similar to this:

```
<?php
$other_page = get_posts( array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'post_type' => 'workshops',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
) );

foreach ( $other_page as $page ) {
    if( have_rows('workshops_grouping', $page->ID) ): ?>
        <select id="no1">
            <?php while( have_rows('workshops_grouping', $page->ID) ): the_row(); ?>
                <option value="<?php the_sub_field('data'); ?>"><?php the_sub_field('data'); ?></option>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </select>
        <select id="no2">
            <?php while( have_rows('workshops_grouping', $page->ID) ): the_row(); ?>
                <option value="<?php the_sub_field('company'); ?>"><?php the_sub_field('company'); ?></option>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </select>
    <?php endif;
}
```

Make sure that the variable $other_page has some pages and the ACF field workshops_grouping has some rows.